# Is it possible that my notebook's USB-C with DisplayPort marking doesn't support 144Hz refresh rate?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport, usb-c

I recently bought a new notebook (Asus G713RS), which of course came with better specs than the older one (GX701GWR).

Both notebooks have a USB-C port with DisplayPort marking, which is what I normally use to let notebook and an external monitor (LG 38GN950) communicate.

The older computer could achieve a 3840 x 1600 resolution at 144Hz refresh rate without any issue, while with the newer one this appears no longer to be possible.

The configuration of the monitor did not change, nor did the USB-C to DisplayPort cable (although I did try another one supporting better specifications, and still it did not work). Of course I updated all the drivers of the newer notebook, and I even tried to re-install both graphics and USB drivers with no avail.

The only refresh rates I can select both on the Nvidia control panel and on Windows are always 60Hz and 75Hz. This is indipendent on the selected resolution: no matter what I select, I can only choose 60Hz or 75Hz. Also, the notebook is running plugged to the AC, so it's not a power supply issue too. I did not enable HDR either and set DSR to off in the Nvidia control panel.

I contacted the assistance, and after a while they told me that "the USB-C port I'm using does not support 144Hz". How is that possible? It has a "DisplayPort" marking, so it actually should, especially if I select lower resolutions.

I guess my question is: is it legit to mark a USB-C port with the DisplayPort symbol, if the full standard specifications are not supported? And why can't I select more than 75Hz even for lower resolutions?

---

**UPDATE**: After a few days of back and forth with Asus' support, they told me that both HDMI and DP over USB-C only support 60Hz no matter the resolution, which is of course impossible.

Comment: The Asus seems to have two USB-C ports. Have you tried the other one?

Comment: It won't work if the graphics card on the laptop doesn't support it, or the monitor doesn't support it, or if the cable doesn't support the bandwidth needed for 144 Hertz. I'd first try swapping the cables (just in case, because it is easy to check).

Comment: @harrymc yes, but that one doesn't support any video output

Comment: @gnasher729 the monitor does, and so does the cable. And I would really be astonished to find out that a 3080 doesn't support it.

Comment: Did you update the BIOS (to download only from the manufacturer's site)?

Comment: Yes, BIOS is up-to-date.

Comment: Which of these [three USB-C port markings](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042843/) is the one found on your port?

Comment: @harrymc none. Mine is a USB-C 3.2 with the logos of DisplayPort and another one of a lightning

Comment: The lightning mark usually means Thunderbolt. However, in photos I have seen on the web, I can't see such markings on the G713RS. Could you put up a photo? Note that DisplayPort has several versions, and only the higher ones will support 144Hz.

Comment: @harrymc I can't at the moment. However, at page 26 of the manual it's written that the port is a displayport/power delivery combo. So I guess the lightning means "power" in this case

Answer (score 2):

It has been pretty hard to find which DisplayPort version is supported
by your laptop, but I have found these sources:

- [ROG Strix G17 G713](https://rog.asus.com/laptops/rog-strix/2021-rog-strix-g17-series/)
- [ASUS ROG Strix G17 G713RS-KH004W](https://www.samitech.it/en/portable-pcs/36568-asus-rog-strix-g17-g713rs-kh004w-6900hx-notebook-439-cm-173-full-hd-amd-ryzen-9-16-gb-ddr5-sdram-1000-gb-ssd-nvidia.html)
- [ROG Strix G17 Advantage Edition G713](https://rog.asus.com/laptops/rog-strix/2021-rog-strix-g17-advantage-edition-series/)

All these source specify DisplayPort 1.4 as the version supported by this
model.

[Wikipedia DisplayPort 1.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.4)
lists these resolution and frequencies:

> Using DSC with HBR3 transmission rates, DisplayPort 1.4 can support 8K UHD (7680 × 4320) at 60 Hz or 4K UHD (3840 × 2160) at 120 Hz with 30 bit/px RGB color and HDR. 4K at 60 Hz 30 bit/px RGB/HDR can be achieved without the need for DSC. On displays which do not support DSC, the maximum limits are unchanged from DisplayPort 1.3 (4K 120 Hz, 5K 60 Hz, 8K 30 Hz).

At your resolution of 3840 x 1600 (or 3840 × 2160?), it seems that Asus
Support were right when saying that
the USB-C port does not support 144Hz.
The maximum possible might be 120 Hz.

This is a high-end laptop, so I find this to be a real shame.
Having both an RTX3080 and a DisplayPort 1.4 USB-C port in the same
computer is really being cheapskate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I do not know if the caveat might be in the displayport on usb. My resolution is 3840 x 1600 (I have a 12:5 monitor) and Asus is not stating that a somewhat lower refresh rate can work, rather that only 60hz does. Regardless of the resolution... And the incredible thing is that this is also exactly what happens (more or less, since I can also select 75hz).

Comment: Try maybe to force it using the [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU), to see how much you can drive this up.

Comment: I tried this path too to no avail. :/

Comment: It's then a real hardware limitation of the port. I think Asus just pushed out an older model with an RTX3080 stuck in, rather than create a new model. If at all possible, I would in your place return it and ask to be reimbursed.

Comment: it was useful, but I'm afraid it still doesn't explain why/how the hardware is limited like that. Moreover I still have no clue if this is a real hardware issue or simply a firmware one :/

Comment: My answer says this is a hardware issue - no software update can force a port to use another DisplayPort version than the one it was built with. You need DisplayPort 2.0, version 1.4 cannot do 144Hz.

Comment: Well, displayport 1.4 can support more than 60Hz on 4k, so why doesn't it, if it is a standard? Also, since there is no difference between resolutions, the only explanation would be that those refresh rates are somehow limited by the firmware

Comment: How am I supposed to know what other components limit further the frequency and what is the quality of the USB-C port that's installed? Evidently it's an old and very limited hardware. Your question was about the 144Hz refresh rate, and this was fully answered. It's your choice, but I can't fix your hardware.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound harsh, but you are not doing anything different than Asus is doing, that is stating something without being able to prove it. It's not evident that it is an old and very limited hardware since the pc is new and your answer still doesn't explain why I'm not able to select any other refresh rates on lower resolutions.

Comment: I found 3 sources that substantiated my answer. Thank you for appreciating my efforts for you.

Comment: in fact I upvoted your answer, thanked you more than once, and you did get the bounty. I'm not going to continue to argue about this.

Comment: No argument, but if you think that you have awarded the bounty, this didn't happen.